# why does documentUrl return null

Tags: java, eclipse, blackberry, web

I'm making a web application for blackberry and I really need the current URL

In the description of `documentUrl`, it says

> This method will return the URL of the currently loaded page of this BrowserField Instance

My code is:

```
_bf2.requestContent("google.com";);
add(_bf2);
Global.c = _bf2.getDocumentUrl();
Global.be=new BasicEditField("URL: "+Global.c,Global.c);
add(Global.be);
```

and the weird thing is that www.google.com gets loaded in the BrowserField and the documentUrl returns null.

This is my current code:

```
BrowserField _bf2 = new BrowserField();
MYBrowserFieldListener _listener = new MYBrowserFieldListener();
_bf2.requestContent("google.com";);
_bf2.addListener(_listener);
String url=_bf2.getDocumentUrl();
Global.be=new BasicEditField("URL: "+url,url);
add(Global.be);
add(_bf2);
```

I changed it to

```
final BrowserField _bf2 = new BrowserField();
_bf2.requestContent("google.com";);
//_bf2.addListener(listener);
Global.be=new BasicEditField("URL: "+Global.c,Global.c);
add(Global.be);
add(_bf2);
_bf2.addListener(new BrowserFieldListener(){
    public void documentLoaded(BrowserField _bf2, Document document) throws Exception {
        Global.c=_bf2.getDocumentUrl();
    }
});
```

But it still returns null. Can someone please tell me how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: String l= browserField.getDocumentUrl;

Comment: This line of code returns null, when I print it on a text field. Can someone please tell me how to fix this in order for me to get the current URL?

Comment: The API says "If no page is loaded, this method will return null". So the only guess is you have not load the page (fully or at all) by the moment you call `getDocumentUrl()`. So again, why don't you post you entire code?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that Arhimed has answered your question. An HTTP request is a very time consuming process (from a CPU perspective) and will block until the server responds. I suspect that RIM programmers have coded the requestContent() method as per their own recommendations and are fetching the web content on a separate thread. So, requestContent() will return immediately, when you call getDocumentUrl() it is still null since the fetch thread has probably not even connected to the server at this point.

You will need to implement a BrowserFieldListener and listen for documentLoaded().

Comment: This is my current code:         BrowserField _bf2 = new BrowserField();

         MYBrowserFieldListener _listener = new MYBrowserFieldListener();
         _bf2.requestContent("http://www.google.com");
         _bf2.addListener(_listener);
         String url=_bf2.getDocumentUrl();
         Global.be=new BasicEditField("URL: "+url,url);
         add(Global.be);
         add(_bf2);

Comment: I used MyBrowserField class from http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/BrowserField-Sample-Code-Using-the-BrowserFieldListener-class/ta-p/496213

Comment: And I'm still getting null value from getDocumentUrl. Someone please help me!

Comment: You are completely missing the way listeners are used. Have a look at my blog: http://www.hrbuckley.net/2011/08/parsing-html-on-blackberry.html This is about using the BrowserField2 to parse HTML but it does show how to implement a listener.

Comment: This is my current code:MyBrowserFieldListener loader = new MyBrowserFieldListener();
         _bf2.addListener(loader);
         String url=_bf2.getDocumentUrl();
         Global.be=new BasicEditField("URL: "+url,url);
            add(Global.be);         
         add(_bf2);
         _bf2.requestContent("http://www.google.com");

Comment: added the listener, and then tried to print out the url=_bf2.getDocumentUrl(); and I still get null, I looked at your code , and I still can't figure out what am I doing wrong. Someone please help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I changed it to:final BrowserField _bf2 = new BrowserField();
         _bf2.requestContent("http://google.com");
         //_bf2.addListener(listener);
         Global.be=new BasicEditField("URL: "+Global.c,Global.c);
         add(Global.be);        
         add(_bf2);  
         _bf2.addListener(new BrowserFieldListener(){
          public void documentLoaded(BrowserField _bf2, Document document) throws Exception
          {
           Global.c=_bf2.getDocumentUrl();
          }
      }); But it still returns null. Can someone please tell me how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are still setting the content of Global.be before the content can be fetched and the value returned by getDocumentUrl() can have a value. You will not get a value other than null until BrowserFieldListener.documentLoaded() is called. You need to set the text content of Global.be in the listener.

Comment: I changed my code to://URL
         final BrowserField _bf2 = new BrowserField();         
         _bf2.requestContent("http://google.com");                  
         add(Global.be);        
         add(_bf2);  
            Document doc =_bf2.getDocument();
         _bf2.addListener(loader.listener);
         loader.listener.documentLoaded(_bf2, doc);

Comment: But now I'm getting null pointer exception and I know that it means that I'm sending a null valued variable, but I don't know which it is and I don't know how to fix it. Can someone please help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: _bf2.getDocument(); is returning null, how can I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: where exactly should I call getDocumentUrl, in order for me to get a value other than null? Thanks in advance! This is My current code:

Comment: BrowserFieldListener listener = new BrowserFieldListener() {
          
       public void documentLoaded(BrowserField _bf2, Document doc)
           throws Exception {
        Global.be1=_bf2.getDocumentUrl();
        super.documentLoaded(_bf2, doc);
         }  
       
        };

Comment: final BrowserField _bf2 = new BrowserField();         
         _bf2.requestContent("http://google.com");         
      Document doc = document;     
         _bf2.addListener(listener);                
         listener.documentLoaded(_bf2, doc);         
         add(new LabelField("URL: "+Global.be1));
         add(_bf2);

Comment: Do you seriously expect people to read horribly formatted code in a comment, and be able to help you? The link you originally provided in you question, and the one I gave you both show you how to implement the listener properly.

Comment: I just have 1 more question. I already made the getDocumentUrl work, but I can't make it appear at the top of the page, because it only gets the url after the browser has been added to the window, so how can I make the url appear at the top of the page? Thanks in advance!